# 0-5V signal output to start 230V DC circuit

Tags: cnc

I would like to ask you how to solve my case.
I need output from PC's paralel port (something between 0-5VDC and low current) to switch 230VAC circuit.
There is 24VDC/5A PLC power supply also, so I know that step from 24VDC to 230VAC (contactor or SSR), but Im completely lost how to safely make the rest.
I read in other topics i need to buffer that signal,but dont know how.
Its for homemade CNC, to start/stop 0,7kW milling machine.
Thanks!
Edit: CNC is plugged in socket and i want start/stop this socket by signal from PC.

Comment: What's the purpose of this control? Safety or normal control with M03/M04? Do you have a VFD or other speed controller on the spindle motor?

Comment: You need to approach this from the perspective of safely controlling the insufficiently described load.  Many modern spindle or motion controllers would have a control input; if you have a crude motor connected directly to the mains, you need something safe for that.

Comment: Purpouse is start milling machine and mainly end it after work. Its normal 230V socket with makita 700W plugged in. No control here. This socket i want to start/stop with signal :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you will be activating a normally open relay to switch the 230VAC, and these relay will be activated by a 24VDC signal. Somehow you need to amplify the TTL level signal from your parallel port to the 24VDC. I have often seen in CNC machines large relays for the mains power that are activated by smaller relays. You can probably drive such a smaller relay with a transistor and possibly a few resistors, depending upon the current requirements of the smaller relay.
I don't know what the current requirements are for the large relay, but https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LCA110.pdf/$file/LCA110.pdf is able to drive 200mA drawing only 2mA input. Do you know if that is sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

There are small parts that will do the job, like *Math Keeps Me Busy* mentioned. If you want something more friendly (screw terminals), use a DC-DC SSR to drive your AC SSR/Contactor. [https://www.amazon.com/WerFamily-Solid-State-SSR-40DD-5-250V/dp/B06XPLQ9JQ](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XPLQ9JQ)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZXCIT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, a solid-state relay is probably what you need, these are available in high-power packages for currents of 10A or so, and in smaller packages such as DIP-7 for lower currents.  They switch with low voltage and current, and importantly they isolate the control signal from the AC supply.  Needless to say, be sure to keep your control signals well isolated elsewhere - running AC on veroboard isn’t a good idea.